# How to call Laravel Custom commands asynchronously from controllers?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a custom command created in laravel 8.x - `'command:downloadAndImport'` which I'm able to call through the controller as below -

```
Artisan::queue('command:downloadAndImport', ['url' => $url, 'path' => $file->path]);
```

What can I do for this call to be an asynchronous call?

Comment: What queue connection is set in the ```queue.php``` file? If it is ```sync``` it will dispatch and handle this command in the same request.

Comment: changing it to `database` gives an error that I need to have a table in the database namesd `jobs`. Does adding that table be considered standard behaviour?

Comment: ``SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel.jobs' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `jobs` (`queue`, `attempts`, `reserved_at`, `available_at`, `created_at`, `payload`)``

This is the error I received.. Can I autogenerate this by any means?

Comment: I think you need to take a look at the docs to see how the queue works: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues To use the ```database``` connection, you should first run this command: ```php artisan queue:table``` and then ```php artisan migrate```. You will find all details needed in the documentation. For production, I recommend something like ```redis``` or ```beanstalkd```.

Comment: This solved the error, but now the command is not actually running.

Comment: You need to run the queue worker ```php artisan queue:work``` to handle the job.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Everything worked finally.